# How to calculate the resonance peak of a NV center during a ESR/ODMR measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, fermis-golden-rule, diamond

I am thinking of making an magnetometer with ODMR measurement of a NV center in nanodiamond. But before I do the experiment, I want to estimate the sensitivity of my experiment beforehand theoretically. I have read some literature about the NV center, but I still have difficulty in calculating the resonance peak since I not a physics major.
The band structure of a NV center is:
[image]
So if I excite the NV center with a microwave, I can pump electrons from ms=0 state to ms=+-1state. By doing ODMR measurement, I will be able to know the population of ms=0 state and ms=+-1 state. So, If I sweep the frequency of the microwave, I would be able to obtain a spectrum like:
[image]
Is there a way to calculate the properties of this peak shown above? Like an expression to describe this peak physically? Assuming we have the NV center's parameter, like coherent time, etc. The microwave used to excite the NV center is Gaussian shaped with a width of d Hz.
Will the excitation time of the microwave (like with a continuous microwave source or a pulsed microwave source ) affect the final peak shape?

Comment: Cool! How strong is the luminescence without the magnetic resonance? Is this the color center that gives the visible blue fluorescence of diamonds? That thing is very strong, you won't need much of optical sensitivity for that detection.

Comment: So this is NV center that has red light luminescence. By sensitivity I mean when I use this NV center for magnetic field sensor, how sensitive will it be.

Comment: Oh, I see... you mean what's the splitting? Yeah, that requires some quantum mechanics. No idea.